# how to load custom single.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, single

Hi I have a blog where the categories are news, events and inspiration. These categories are selected using radio buttons on acf. I want to load news on single-news.php while events on single-events.php and inspiration on single-inspiration.php

is it possible to use the acf fields to do this?
I have came across this code with wordpress default categories to load custom single.php

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
if (in_category('1')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single1.php');
} elseif (in_category('2')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single2.php');
} else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single_default.php');
}
```

what can be used instead of the ‘in_category’ while using acf?

thanks guys.

Comment: I can't say I've done this, but you could probably use the template_include filter, test if you're on a certain category, then use a specific tempalte - View Codex. Another option would be to open your single.php and add a conditional at the top, right below get_header() then do what you're already doing.

Comment: Have you checked [ACF's support site](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

Comment: If your ACF radio buttons are actually assigning the taxonomy terms to the post (Load & Save Terms to Post option selected using the Taxonomy field type), then it would work exactly the same way. Since you haven't specified *how* that data is saved, a definitive answer is impossible.